# how to check a choicetype box as default

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony5

How do I check PMTool checkbox as default? Also I don't want this to override the data when I modify the existing user.

```
-> add('raw_roles', ChoiceType:: class, [
    'label' => 'User access',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => [
        'PMTool' => 'ROLE_USER',
        'SPOC' => 'ROLE_SPOC_USER',
        'Debug' => 'ROLE_SOAP_USER',
    ],
    data => ['ROLE_USER'],
])
```

I tried acheiving the desired result with the code above but when I modify an existing user PMTool checkbox is getting checked automatically and not saving without unchecking it.

Answer (score 0):

Callback to return `['ROLE_USER']` to check the "PMTool" checkbox by default. Otherwise, we return an empty array `[]` to leave the checkbox unchecked. ([Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#advanced-example-with-objects))

```
->add('raw_roles', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'User access',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => [
        'PMTool' => 'ROLE_USER',
        'SPOC' => 'ROLE_SPOC_USER',
        'Debug' => 'ROLE_SOAP_USER',
    ],
    'data' => function ($value, $user) {
        // Check if the user already has the 'ROLE_USER' (PMTool) role
        if (in_array('ROLE_USER', $user->getRoles())) {
            return ['ROLE_USER'];
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    },
])
```